# Access a Razor View from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a MVC project that is using Razor Views for my website.  One of my projects, lets call it project1 is complete and in use.

I would like to access a view in project1 from project2 so that I do not have to maintain both screen.

They are both in the same solution.

I cannot change project1 since it is already in use by our customers. I looked at the Razor Single File Generator but that is quite drastic for 1 screen and I cannot change project1 that is in use already.

How do I reference the view from project1 in my project2?

Thanks!

Comment: Theoretically, I believe you can "Add as Link..." from the Add Existing Item dialog, and choose the file from the other project.

Comment: If I make changes to it, does it affect both? I understand it's a link but the path in the properties shows it where I (newly) added it.

Comment: Correct. The version in your other project is basically like a Windows Shortcut at that point. It's a shared file.

Comment: Also be warned that MSBuild might have a small problem with copying this shared file when you publish it - you might need to add a custom MSBuild step for that guy.

Comment: It doesn't see any of my references from project1 from the link and I wasn't able to compile.

Comment: Am I the only one that sees some lack of logic in his question? `so that I do not have to maintain both screen` vs `I cannot change project1 since it is already in use by our customers.`

Comment: I'm not sure where it lacks logic to you... but I cannot change project1 and project2 needs to be able to call that screen in project1.  Shall I explain it further to you?

Comment: *more than just 1 screen but multiple screen

Answer (score 2):

You could compile your views from project2 into a dll and reference that dll in project1.

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) to compile a view into a dll.

Comment: We did look at this but it requires us to make drastic changes to project1 that we want to avoid.

Comment: could you describe what drastic changes you mean? I really can't see any other changes but (1) including a reference, (2) setting your controller actions to return referenced Views where appropriate. Perhaps it would be helpful to describe limitations of project1 (other than it's in production) to get better answers